# Keep processes running after SSH session disconnecting from a jump machine

Tags: ssh

I know `screen` can let the processes keep running after disconnecting from a ssh session, if I’m doing something like: *local machine -> ssh -> server*.

But I need to access a server through a jump machine: *local machine -> ssh -> jump machine -> ssh -> server*. Now if I use `screen` and ssh back to the server, the `screen` sessions are lost as well.

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/autossh

Comment: this shouldn't be a problem. `screen` has to run on _server_ but not on _jump machine_. if the session dies, no matter wich one, you can open the tunnel again and get your screen back

Answer (score 0):

Use the `disown` command. Start the process and append with `disown`. For example:

```
$ ping google.com & disown
```